# Application Insights Error with instrumentation key

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have 7 applications already deployed and they have been using AI for more than 1 year already.
Suddenly I start receiving application insights errors in the browser.

The error is this one

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Invalid instrumentation key)  dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track:1

I haven't changed my instrumentation key, I have entered and check that the Instrumentation Keys are ok.

Does anyone have experience this?

Thank you

Comment: have you used fiddler to check if the correct key is used?

Comment: or for a testing purpose, can you create a new app with this app insights to see if it works well?

Comment: Hello @IvanYang i haven't use fiddler will use it now, and yes will create a new resource on app insights to check and will let you know today. But this happened suddenly i haven't published any app in a while, and I just noticed that none of my app were submitting metrics. Thanks

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: Hello, @IvanYang sorry for the delay I was out for a couple of days, after research a lot i decided to remove a resource and create a new one for one of the applications when i was creating the resource i was not able because there was an issue with the account. Azure never send me an email, or i never saw in the notification that there was an issue with the account. everything always looks fine, that was the first think i check.
So I have contacted azure and they are taking a look to the account and the whole issue was related to that. But no notifications at all, that is sad.Thank you

Comment: Hope that they can fix it asap.